# Spring MVC - mvc resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo, spring-webflow

I have a spring project where, on a linux/tomcat6 server we have an external folder for person photos inside "**/var/projectname/personphotos**". Tried making a symbolic link and the like and nothing seems to work, the application cannot see the external folder. I happened to stunble upon the `<mvc:resources>` tag and the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` .How do I add it to the project ?
I was thinking something like

`<mvc:resources mapping="/personphotos/" location="/var/projectname/personphotos" />`

and in the application i can have something like `<img src="/personphotos/bla-bla.jpg"/>`

All of the tutorials say to use the tags but they don't say where to place it. I assume the location must be understood, forgive my ignorance. I tried adding it to the applicationcontext.xml and that blew-up with errors. Other tutorials were saying to edit the servlet-context.xml, wherever that is ? see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784060/spring-tomcat-and-static-resources-and-mvcresources)

I am using spring 3.0.7 with STS and I tried changing to 3.1.0 in the pom file. The version change caused mvn tomcat:run to give some errors. I saw somewhere that the mvc:resource tage was available in 3.0.4 or highter, i guess I am safe for now. Please help to clear up these ambiguities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be in your servlet-context.xml file, probably this way:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/personphotos/**" location="/var/projectname/personphotos" />
```

and you can access it using:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/personphotos/bla-bla.jpg"/>
```

the starting part is to make sure that you application context part gets added in too.

**EDIT**
For the benefit of others, the Final thing which is working is

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/personphotos/**" location="file:/var/projectname/personphotos" />
```

Comment: I cannot find a file called servlet-context.xml in my project. I can find context.xml inside"src/main/webapp/META-INF" apart form that there is the applicationcontext.xml inside "src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationcontext.xml". I am not sure where to find servlet-context.xml

Comment: yes, I meant the context file that you have registered against the DispatcherServlet, look in your web.xml , you should see an entry for DispatcherServlet, the init-param value should indicate which application context file it uses - it should be the context.xml file that you have indicated

Comment: You were correct, I found the correct file. I am trying ti test if it works on windows but I am not geting the image to load here is my entry    <mvc:resources mapping="/personphotos/**" location="classpath:C:/Users/faiyo/Pictures/" /> Not sure if I am doing it correct.

Comment: No, `classpath:` with a file system path will not work, if you have it in filesystem try this instead `file:/C:/Users/faiyo/Pictures/`